# Antlr4: grammars-4/javascript C++ port questions

Tags: c++, antlr, antlr4

I’m trying to port grammars-4/javascript grammar on C++ with an approach used in already presented C# and Java implementations. (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/javascript). 
First, let me explain how C# and Java implementations provide generated Lexer and Parser code for clients. For example each, implementation defines the base class for Lexer - `JavaScriptBaseClass` - with defined methods `NextToken()`, `RegexPossible()` etc., which is naturally inherited from Antlr Lexer class. Grammar file `JavaScriptLexer.g4` defines `JavaScriptBaseLexer` as superclass for the generated lexer.
At the same time some entities which will be available only after `JavaScriptLexer` source code generation are used inside the defined methods of base class `JavaScriptBaseClass`.
For example `JavaScriptBaseLexer::NextToken` method uses `OpenBrace` enum value which describes one of the tokens of the grammar.(https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/a2b8cdfae4057f330f1ec46e8b8e87ea3e7ad962/javascript/CSharpSharwell/JavaScriptBaseLexer.cs#L68)
This is the feature of C# or Java not to predefine header files and then include them in code where the name from the header file could appear. So, it is alright to use the fields of not yet generated source code of `JavaScriptLexer`  class inside the base class.

But how this could be achieved in C++ implementation?
First, generated class must know the definition of its parent, so the directive `#include “JavaScriptBaseLexer.h”` needs to be presented in generated `JavaScriptLexer.h` file, 
otherwise the code will not compile since base class name undefined. It seems lexer’s option `header` could be added into lexer’s grammar file,

```
lexer::header {
  #include "JavaScriptBaseLexer.h"
}
```

but the options are not language specific and will appear in C#/Java lexer generated code, and that is not expected in C#/Java code.

Second, `JavaScriptLexer’s` token enum needs to be defined somewhere before the source code generation to be used inside base class code. This issue could be solved by including generated `JavaScriptLexer.h` inside the `JavaScriptBaseLexer.cpp` file. Looks strange…

Any ideas how to implement С#/Java approach in C++? I’ll appreciate any help. 
Thank you.